# onPause() called at startup

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-lifecycle, fragmentpageradapter

I'm experiencing a strange (maybe it's normal...) behaviour. I've a activity with a **viewpager** and inside it 3 fragment. I'm using FragmentPagerAdapter and setOffScreenPageLimit = 3.
When I deploy the apk to my device (N4) **the very first time** the app opens up, **after onResume, onPause method is called**. This is causing me some issues, cause I override onPause inside the fragment and I've some specific behaviour. After deploying, even if I completely kill the app and reopen it, this is not happening anymore. What's the point here? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What device do you have? Maybe a HTC device? And are you deploying in debug mode?

Comment: For those offscreen fragments, `onCreate` is called, but they are not visible, so I think it's logical to call `onPause` on them.

@XaverKapeller He mentioned Device. It's LG Nexus 4

Comment: I'm deploying on a Nexus 4. @Marius: to me it's logical too, BUT I'm not having the same behaviour the second time, I need to know what's going to happen =)

Comment: Anyway `onPause()` shouldn't contain code that can mess things up. Those lifecycle methods may be called at any time as you experienced yourself. As for the reason why `onPause()` is called: @Marius is probably right that `onPause()` is called on not visible `Fragments`, but it is also possible that the debugger is causing the `Activity` to go to the background for just a second causing `onPause()` to be called. HTC devices are also notorious for opening some `Dialog`/`Activity` when deploying an app.

Comment: Ok, so I can't refer to activity lifecycle described in the official doc. I use onPause method to stop a surface camera preview, I think that's the right place to do that, but that way, when I swipe to that fragment I obviously have no camera preview.

Comment: The solution to your problem is this: when `onPause()` is called, then `onResume()` **HAS** to be called before the `Fragment` is displayed again. You are correct for stopping the camera preview in `onPause()`, what is missing is that you start it again in `onResume()`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your advice. Anyway I exported the apk and manually installed (no IDE) it on the phone: onPause in not called anymore.